# automation of re-enabling a pytest

Tags: python, pytest

In my testing platform if a tests starts to fail we create a bug report for it and mark the test as xfail or skipif using pytest decorators. In the reason parameter we always associate the bug report number. Once a new release is released that is suppose to fix one of the bugs we have to manually go in and re enable the test. Manual work doesn't get done 100% of the time though.

Is there anyway to automate the removal of a pytest xfail or skipif marker assuming during each release I will get a list of bug report numbers that are "fixed"?

Comment: In the spirit of TDD you should fix the code instead of deactivating the test. If the tests don't run you don't check your code in.

Comment: It's a large team I am just a tester and I don't have access to commit to the developer repo. Anyway I think I found a solution just need to test it out before posting my answer.